# A word to describe tools of the workplace

Tags: word-request, adjectives, nouns

What group do work or office tools, devices, widgets, gizmos and accessories belong to ?

*Examples : post-it notes, calendar, address book, kanban board, phone...*

From my understanding, "stationary" only describes paper and paper-specific tools. I'm looking to gather under one noun (or adjective) all the work-enabling artifacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase most commonly used to describe this in English is [office supplies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_supplies).

As an addendum, the word used to refer to paper products is ["stationery"](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/stationery); stationary means not moving.